# Instance variable is not initialized. Why is that?

Tags: vdm++

I got this problem with my instance variables. They will not be initialized and I'm unsure what is exactly means. It's the same for every class I have. I posted one of the codes below:

```
class Good
types
  public evalGood :: 
  good : Good
  price : nat1;

 instance variables
    private owner : Seller;
    private startPrice : nat1;
    private description : seq of char

operations
  public  getStartPrice : ()  ==> nat1
  getStartPrice() == (return startPrice);

end Good
```

I hope someone can help me and maybe explain why, so it doesn't happen again

Regards,
Kamilla

Answer (score 0):

When you declare instance variables, their values are "undefined" - ie. no particular value - unless you assign them. You can either do that with an initializer (say ":= 123" on the end) or set them to a value in a constructor. If you do neither, Overture will give you this warning. It is not necessarily an error, but you must set the variables to a value before you use them.

Comment: Hi Nick. Thank you very much. I think that helped me. Can it be because I have only worked 'implicit' that I didn't catch/understood this mistake?

Can you try to assign the '123' to my code to make an example? I think that would clear up a few things too.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I mean you can change the definition to "private startPrice:nat1 := 123". That may make little sense(!), but it would remove the warning for that one field.